# if condition to check if only one variable is set of the four variables at any point in JAVA

Tags: java, logic, logical-operators

I want to display an error if more than one of the four variables is set...
In Java..this is what I came up with..

```
if( (isAset() && isBset()) || (isBset() && isCset()) || (isCset() && isDset()) || (isDset() && isAset()) )
    attri.greedySelectionException(..);
```

I wanted to check if there is a better way of doing this..?

Comment: If A and C were true your expression would return false :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about you use a counter and then compare it to 1?

Something like...

```
int i = 0;
if (isAset()) i++;
if (isBset()) i++;
if (isCset()) i++;
if (isDset()) i++;

if (i > 1)
  ...
```

Alternatively, if you are checking properties of a certain object, you could use some reflection to iterate through the relevant properties instead of having one if statement per property.

Edit: Take a look at Marius Žilėnas's varargs static method below for some tidier code, i.e. using (changed the oldschool for to a for-each and the ternary expression for an if):

```
static int trueCount(boolean... booleans) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (boolean b : booleans) {
    if (b) {
      sum++;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

instead of several if statements.

Comment: This looks less cumbersome and a lot better than my logic. Thanks!

Comment: With Java 8, it can be written as
   `static long trueCount(Boolean... booleans) {
   return Arrays.stream(booleans)
     .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
     .count();
  }`

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify this expression with :

```
if((isAset() || isCset()) && (isBset() || isDset()))
   attri.greedySelectionException(..);
```

Wolfram alpha made the work for you :

[Original expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+%28A+AND+B%29+OR+%28B+AND+C%29+OR+%28C+AND+D%29+OR+%28D+AND+A%29+%29+)

You can verify with the truth tables :

[Original](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%20%28A%20AND%20B%29%20OR%20%28B%20AND%20C%29%20OR%20%28C%20AND%20D%29%20OR%20%28D%20AND%20A%29%20%29%20truth%20table)

[Final](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%28A%20OR%20C%29%20AND%20%28B%20OR%20D%29%20truth%20table)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP contains an error in the expression, i.e. it does not consider `A` & `C`. Thanks for a link to Wolfram Alpha, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 you can solve this problem with Streams in an elegant way (assuming your values are null if they are not set):

```
if (Stream.of(valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD).filter(Objects::nonNull).count() != 1) { 
    /* throw error */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [varargs ...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) (see Java tutorial) and  make a function that calculates how many trues was given. The following code to demonstrates it:

```
public class Values
{
    public static boolean isASet()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean isBSet()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isCSet()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isDSet()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static int booleans(boolean... booleans)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++)
        {
            sum += booleans[i] ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(
                booleans(isASet(), isBSet(), isCSet(), isDSet()));
        if (1 < booleans(isASet(), isBSet(), isCSet(), isDSet()))
        {
            System.out.println("Condition met.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control on the implementation of isAset(), isBSet, isCSet, & isDset methods, you can achieve this with much more clarity if you return 1 or 0 instead of true or fales from this functions. These functions are to be created as below...

```
public int isAset()
{
   return (A != null) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

To verify if more than one variable is set use use something like below...

```
if( isASet() + isBSet() + isCSet() + isDSet() > 1)
     ThrowMoreAreSetException()
```

If you don't have control on this here is another way of doing it...

```
int count = isASet() ? 1 : 0;
count+= isBSet() ? 1 : 0;
count+= isCSet() ? 1 : 0;
count+= isDSet() ? 1 : 0;

if(count > 1)
 ThrowMoreAreSetException()
```

By following either of these approches, code will be less clumsy and more readable than doing somany comparision combinations.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
if (!(isAset ^ isBset ^ isCset ^ isDset))
```

This will true only is any one is true or else false.

Comment: First, that is FALSE if only one is true (there is a negation at the beginning). Moreover, if three of them are true, XOR is also true.

Comment: I don't think the expression is accurate. All four of the booleans wont be operated at once, the expression will be evaluated from left to right so `true ^ true ^ true ^ false` and `true ^ false ^ false ^ false` will be evaluated to same values. So obviously this expression doesn't give what is expected of it.

Comment: What I meant exactly. By the way, the order in which a n-ary XOR is evaluated doesn't affect the outcome, as XOR is an associative operator.